# SwiftUI - How do I create Global @State Variables?

Tags: swiftui

Is it possible to create a global @State variable in SwiftUI that can be accessed across multiple Swift UI files?

I've looked into @EnvironmentObject variables but can't seem to make them do what I want them to do.

Comment: There's no such thing as global @State variables. EnvironmentObject is the way to go. I suggest you check WWDC session Data Flow in SwiftUI. It is very well explained there.

Comment: Btw, If you are having problems making EnvironmentObject, update your answer with some code and explain what you are trying to achieve. Then people will be able to help.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will refer to the WWDC session.

Answer (score 7):

As of Beta 3 you cannot create a top-level global `@State` variable.  The compiler will segfault.  You can place one in a struct and create an instance of the struct in order to build.  However, if you actually instantiate that you'll get a runtime error like: `Accessing State<Bool> outside View.body`.

Probably what you're looking for is an easy way to create a binding to properties on a `BindableObject`.  There's a good example of that in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/chriseidhof/603354ee7d52df77f7aec52ead538f94).

It is possible to create a `Binding` to a global variable, but unfortunately this still won't do what you want.  The value will update, but your views will not refresh (code example below).

Example of creating a `Binding` programmatically:

```swift
var globalBool: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        // This will get called
        NSLog("Did Set" + globalBool.description)
    }
}

struct GlobalUser : View {

    @Binding var bool: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("State: \(self.bool.description)") // This will never update
            Button("Toggle") { self.bool.toggle() }
        }
    }
}

...
static var previews: some View {
    GlobalUser(bool: Binding<Bool>(getValue: { globalBool }, setValue: { globalBool = $0 }))
}
...
```